# Debugging unexpected results from pipelined powershell function with background scriptblock

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I'm wrestling with an unexpected result from a powershell function once I enable pulling values from the pipeline. The function in question consumes a list of hostnames and retrieves information about missing updates. When taking the hostnames as an array (second code sample) and iterating to build the set of background tasks, the function works as intended. As soon as I refactor to use the pipeline, I run into some sort of conflict that I believe is related to scope or thread safety -- the result of each query is generated for the localhost rather than the specified host.

I've spent more than a day researching and troubleshooting without any different outcome. I've tried:

- Changing variable/parameter names within the scriptblock and the function
- Moving the scriptblock between Begin and Process
- Creating the background task with a closure of the scriptblock
- Creating independent Runspaces rather than a RunspacePool
- Retrieving results from a output data collector vs EndInvoke
- Running outside the ISE
- Several versions of the End block

I've also added various debug statements and modified the return values to confirm that both the Process block and the scriptblock receive distinct hostnames as expected in the pipeline version.

Anybody able to offer insight about what I'm misunderstanding in terms of scoping and thread safety in Powershell?

*Note: I've disabled the connectivity test to force exceptions in the scriptblock when I pass an invalid host.*

### Pipelined Version

```
function Get-UpdateDetail {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName,
        [string]$Criteria = "IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0"
    )
    Begin {

        $RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,10)
        $RunspacePool.Open()
        $Jobs = @() 
        $Results = @()  
    }
    Process {

        Write-Verbose "Connecting to $ComputerName"

        if(1) { #Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -count 1 -quiet) {

            $Thread = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
                param ($A, $B)
                Try {

                    [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session", $A)).CreateUpdateSearcher().Search($B)
                } Catch {
                    $_.Exception
                }
            }).AddParameter("A",$ComputerName).AddParameter("B",$Criteria)

            $Thread.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool

            $Jobs += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Host = $ComputerName
                Thread = $Thread
                Handle = $Thread.BeginInvoke()
            }
        }
        else {
            $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Host = $ComputerName
                Results = "Offline"
            }
        }
    }
    End {

        While ( $Jobs.Handle.IsCompleted -contains $false) {

            $Remaining = $($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle.IsCompleted -eq $False}).count
            $Complete = ($Jobs.count - $Remaining)/$Jobs.count * 100
            Write-Progress `
                -Activity "Waiting for remaining jobs to complete ..." `
                -PercentComplete $Complete

            ForEach ($Job in $($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle.IsCompleted -eq $True})) {
                Write-Progress `
                    -Activity "Waiting for remaining jobs to complete ..." `
                    -Status "Finishing background job for $($Job.Host)" `
                    -PercentComplete $Complete

                $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Host = $Job.Host
                    Thread = $Job.Thread
                    Handle = $Job.Handle
                    Results = $Job.Thread.EndInvoke($Job.Handle)
                }
                $Job.Thread.Dispose()
                $Job.Thread = $Null
                $Job.Handle = $Null
            }
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }

        $RunspacePool.Close()
        $RunspacePool.Dispose()
        $Results
    }
}
```

### Array Version

```
function Get-UpdateDetail {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [string[]]$ComputerName,
        [string]$Criteria = "IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0"
    )


    $RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,10)
    $RunspacePool.Open()
    $Jobs = @() 
    $Results = @()  

    ForEach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {

        Write-Verbose "Connecting to $Computer"

        if(1) { Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -count 1 -quiet) {

            $Thread = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
                param ($A, $B)
                Try {

                    [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session", $A)).CreateUpdateSearcher().Search($B)
                } Catch {
                    $_.Exception
                }
            }).AddParameter("A",$Computer).AddParameter("B",$Criteria)

            $Thread.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool

            $Jobs += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Host = $Computer
                Thread = $Thread
                Handle = $Thread.BeginInvoke()
            }
        }
        else {
            $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Host = $Computer
                Results = "Offline"
            }
        }
    }

    While ( $Jobs.Handle.IsCompleted -contains $false) {

        $Remaining = $($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle.IsCompleted -eq $False}).count
        $Complete = ($Jobs.count - $Remaining)/$Jobs.count * 100
        Write-Progress `
            -Activity "Waiting for remaining jobs to complete ..." `
            -PercentComplete $Complete

        ForEach ($Job in $($Jobs | Where-Object {$_.Handle.IsCompleted -eq $True})) {
            Write-Progress `
                -Activity "Waiting for remaining jobs to complete ..." `
                -Status "Finishing background job for $($Job.Host)" `
                -PercentComplete $Complete

            $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Host = $Job.Host
                Thread = $Job.Thread
                Handle = $Job.Handle
                Results = $Job.Thread.EndInvoke($Job.Handle)
            }
            $Job.Thread.Dispose()
            $Job.Thread = $Null
            $Job.Handle = $Null
        }
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }

    $RunspacePool.Close()
    $RunspacePool.Dispose()
    $Results

}
```

Comment: How will the pipelined version be operated if `AddParameter("A",$ComputerName)`
will be changed to `AddParameter("A","$ComputerName")` or `AddParameter("A",$ComputerName[0])`?